# Python Function throwing TypeError, says I entered an argument, when I clearly didn't

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

I'm in a bit of a problem. I am trying to bind a function to a mouse click in Python's tkinter module. The function adds 1 to a variable every time you click. This function takes no arguments. However, when I bind the function to the mouse click, It says:

```
TypeError: func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.
```

I never gave the function any arguments and just binded it to the mouse click, and Python still thinks I did something wrong. Help? Code is attached.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title("Sim Game")
c = Canvas(root, height=400, width=600, bg='red')
x = 0
def func():
    global x
    x += 1
c.bind("<Button-1>", func)

c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you add more error traceback?

Comment: I believe when Tk calls the function, it does pass an `event` argument (in this case the button click).  If you don't care about the button click, then add a parameter to the function declaration and forget about it.

Comment: A tiny bit of research would have shown that functions receive an event object when called from an event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a few options:

```
def func(event=None)
```

or

```
c.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: func())
```

Comment: You guys are literal geniuses. Thanks!

Comment: Should be `lambda e: func()` instead.

Comment: @Matiiss no, I think they mean `lambda: func` is incorrect. For starters, you definitly want  the lambda to *call* `func()`, but also, this lambda takes no arguments, so it will produce the same exact error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as far as I know there is not that much difference between lambda: func and lambda e: func()

Comment: @Matiiss they are two completely different things. Try it for yourself. `def foo(): return 42` the try `(lambda: foo)()` and `(lambda: foo())()`

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but not in this case because it will work either way with lambda: func or lambda e: func() (notice the 'e') and in this situation u can as well set func variable event=None

Comment: now I see I was always using it when I also defined func variable event=None thx

Comment: @Matiiss no *you don't understand what I'm trying to say*. With all due respect, you are flat out wrong.

Comment: @Matiiss again, you should try: `def foo(): return 42` the try `print((lambda: foo)())` and `print((lambda: foo())())` to see the difference.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried and it returned different results